# Power BI Parameters and Manual data entry for each row in a table visualization

Tags: parameters, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I am working on a new requirement where I am a little confused how to approach this problem.

I have a table in Power BI containing columns: labor categories and their associated rates. I have already built a table visualization that lists all labor categories and their respected rates, along with a slicer for filtering. The table can be filtered by multiple labor categories.

The goal is to perform a what-if cost analysis.When a few labor category gets selected from the drop down menu and it is populated in the table, the user should be able to enter projected hours for each row of labor category to calculate the estimated cost.

Is there any way I can do this in power bi? Could this be done with any other app integration

I created a parameter in power bi, where I can enter the total projected hours for all selected Labor Categories. The problem with that is it multplies each row of Labor categorie's Rate with that specific number which leads to an overestimate. It doesn't allow me to specify projected hours for each Labors catgories